# How do I translate the following constraint for gurobi py?

Tags: optimization, modeling, python, gurobi, gurobipy

I successfully worked on the problem with following model in Excel, but I have a problem translating it into Python.

[image]

This is the proposed way to code the problem form the book:

```
model "E-6 van rental"
 uses "mmxprs"
 declarations
  NM = 6
  MONTHS = 1..NM
  CONTR = 3..5
  REQ: array(MONTHS) of integer
  COST: array(CONTR) of integer
  NINIT: integer
! Months
! Contract types
! Monthly requirements
! Cost of contract types
! Vans rented at beginning of plan
           rent: array(CONTR,MONTHS) of mpvar  ! New rentals every month
          end-declarations
          initializations from ’e6vanrent.dat’
           REQ COST NINIT
          end-initializations
         ! Objective: total cost
          Cost:= sum(c in CONTR, m in MONTHS) COST(c)*rent(c,m)
         ! Fulfill the monthly requirements
          forall(m in MONTHS)
           if(m<=2, NINIT, 0) +
            sum(c in CONTR, n in maxlist(1,m-c+1)..minlist(m,NM-c+1)) rent(c,n) >=
REQ(m)
         ! Solve the problem
          minimize(Cost)
end-model
```

---

And so far this is what I came up with:
I am especially confused about the constraint.

```
# Model
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

# Data (Set and Parameter)
NM = 6  # Number of months
Months = range(NM)
Contr = [3,4,5]  # Contract Types
REQ = [430, 410, 440, 390, 425, 450]  # Monthly requirement for vans
Cost = [1700,2200,2600] # Cost of contract types
NINIT = 200 # Vans rented at the beginning of plan

# Create a new model
model = gp.Model("Fleet Vans")

# Create decision variables
rent = model.addVars(Contr, Months, vtype=GRB.INTEGER,name="rent")

# Set objective function: Minimize rent cost
Cost = start.sum()
model.setObjective(Cost, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Constraints
# Constraint 1: Fulfill the monthly requirements
for m in Months:
    model.addConstr(if(m<=2, NINIT, 0) + sum(rent[c,n] for c in [3, 4, 5]) >= REQ[m])
    
# Optimize the model
model.optimize()

# Print the solution
if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print("Optimal cost:")
    
    print("Total cost:", Total.getValue())
else:
    print("No solution found.")
```

This is the problem by the way:
[image]

Comment: I suggest you write your mathematical model explicitely first, and not the corresponding code (harder to read).

Comment: Better, but still very hard to read. I suggest you write your problem yourself with MathJax (instead of inserting an image).

Comment: I agree with @Kuifje. Also, does your code work? What is your specific question?

Comment: I need to make the code work to output optimum cost but my constraint is not working,

Answer (score 0):

```
!Define dict NIN
NIN = {1:NINT, 2:NINT, 3:0,4:0,5:0}
for m in Months:
       model.addConstr(NIN[m] + sum(rent[c,n] for c in [3, 4, 5]) >= REQ[m])
```